# Can we invoke data from class without getter and setter methods

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible for visualforce page to get values from apex class without using  getter and setter methods? if yes means Please provide an Simple Example

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To me it sounds like an interview question rather than solving any particular use case here.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the get and set properties on the Apex variables themselves:

`public String myVar { get; set; }`

You can also adjust the access level on the get and set themselves, so if you want to make the variable read-only on the Visualforce page, try this:

`public String myVar { public get; private set; }`

Comment: Those are getter and setter methods though.

Comment: I thought he was referring to explicit getter/setter methods, like `public String getMyVar() { return myVar; }`.

Answer (score 2):

Visualforce can only access *properties*, not *variables*. The difference between a property and a variable is that they have a getter and/or setter. There are three ways to write getters and setters.

## Automatic Getters/Setters

These are getters and setters with no method body:

```
public String var1 { get; set; }
public String var2 { set; }
public String var3 { get; }
```

The get method returns the current value, set sets a new value.

## Manual Getters/Setters

These allow you to add custom logic:

```
private Integer mPercentage;
public Integer percentage { 
  get { return mPercentage == null? 0: mPercentage; }
  set { if(value != null && value >= 0 && value <= 100) mPercentage = value; }
}
```

This code automatically forces a value between 0 and 100, and rejects any other changes.

## Getter and Setter Methods

```
String mFirstName;
public String getFirstName() {
  return mFirstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String value) {
  mFirstName = value;
}
```

All of these methods are referred to as getters and setters, even when a backing variable is used. It is not possible to access any controller variables without a getter or setter.